# How do I achieve frame-by-frame viewing of video?

Tags: media9

The effect I aim to produce can be witnessed by downloading and opening the PDF at the link below.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5s0xdpqyc8lfwvj/AABYk_I4dYXQk9gIiP1cn30Xa?dl=0

As you can see if you download it, clicking the orange 'film' icon opens a window for showing a video clip. But you must download it and run it locally for this to work since the legacy media (MOV files) that it uses is now blocked in browsers for security reasons (that being one reason I'm turning to LaTeX).

The code below supplied by Alex Grahn (although without the stepping parameter) has solved my earlier problem of needing a tiny icon that opens the video in a much larger window.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
    %label=firsttry,
    addresource=40631.mp4,
    windowed=640x480@tr,
    noplaybutton,
    activate=onclick,
    flashvars={source=40631.mp4&autoPlay=true&**stepping=true**}
  ]{\includegraphics[width=32px,height=32px]{filmicon32x32.png}}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

But some problems remain, and the one I focus on in current question is as follows:

**How can I enable readers to step through the video one frame at a time?**

As you can see (assuming you are running AcrobatReaderMediaIcons.pdf locally), with the legacy (MOV) media one can step through the video one frame at a time by clicking the tiny controls in the lower right of the video window. However, when I specify stepping in the code above two problems arise:

1. It pre-empts the activate=onclick parameter; that is, instead of watching the full video when one clicks on it the first time, then shifting to frame-by-frame mode when desired, one is placed directly in frame-by-frame mode from the start.
2. One has to click several times (ranging from 2 to 12 or more in my experience) to move forward one frame.
3. Pressing space bar leads to a jump not of a single frame but what appears to be a full second.

(Just for comparison, when I try this with VideoPlayer.swf in lieu of VPlayer.swf, no frame-by-frame capability is provided at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to frame-wise stepping with `VPlayer.swf` is by clicking onto the video but keeping the mouse button pressed. Then, by releasing the mouse button for a short moment and re-pressing it immediately afterwards the video advances by a very small, perhaps frame-wise step. Don't use `stepping` Flashvar for this.

Comment: I think about removing `stepping`, because it never worked reliably.

Comment: Clicking and releasing the mouse does not provide sufficiently precise control. But thanks for answering my question by clarifying the limitations of the LaTeX + media9 + Flash combination as currently available.